# Wait until TestName != "NoName"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am getting the player names from the server and it takes a while, I have added a function that should wait for the `TestName` variable to be overwritten by the player name

`StartTask()` is invoked via another function but does not wait until `TestName != "NoName"`

```
private string TestName = "NoName";
```

⠀

```
void OnLeaderboardGet(GetLeaderboardResult result)
{
    foreach (var item in result.Leaderboard)
    {
        TestName = "NoName";
        GetPlayerProfile(item.PlayFabId); //This function gets the player's nickname, but with a delay of a few seconds

        StartCoroutine(StartTask());

        Leaders += (TestName + "\n");
    }
    Debug.Log(Leaders);
}

IEnumerator StartTask()
{
    Debug.Log("Start");

    yield return new WaitUntil(CheckName);

    Debug.Log("Finish");
}

bool CheckName(){
    if (TestName == "NoName")
    {
        return false;
    }
    else 
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code isn't a [mcve]. Can you provide one?

Comment: What if I as a player use `NoName` is my name? ^^ -> I would rather actually use `private string TestName = null;` and `yield return new WaitUntil(() => TestName != null);`

Comment: @derHugo Now almost all players have a name = ```null```, If I write
```yield return new WaitUntil(() => TestName != "NoName");``` it still doesn't work

Comment: @Enigmativity I added more code, is that enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post your server request code but it also should be async operation and it should be able work like this way.

Your new yield statement could also be another async operation. that should fix your problem in case it is `GetPlayerProfile`

```cs
//you can ignore that with lambda like += result => StartCoroutine(OnLeaderboardGetCoroutine(result));
void OnLeaderboardGet(GetLeaderboardResult result)
{
   StartCoroutine(OnLeaderboardGetCoroutine(result));
}


IEnumerator OnLeaderboardGetCoroutine(GetLeaderboardResult result)
{
    foreach (var item in result.Leaderboard)
    {
        TestName = "NoName";
        yield return GetPlayerProfile(item.PlayFabId); //This function gets the player's nickname, but with a delay of a few seconds

        //StartCoroutine(StartTask());

        Leaders += (TestName + "\n");
    }
    Debug.Log(Leaders);
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error ```CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'``` when executing the line ```yield return GetPlayerProfile(item.PlayFabId);```

Comment: @oistikbal - Please post working code whenever it is possible. I go to great lengths to ensure the code I post works. You have a rep of 212, why would you say "never expect full working code at here"?